# Select an object by clicking it

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that changes colour of shapes on worksheet on clicking a specific shape.

However, when I click this shape it doesn´t really select it, so I cannot differ this "clicked image" from the others, because clicking doesn´t select the shape.

How can I select the shape by clicking it executing a macro at the same time?

I need to execute this macro:

```
For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
shp.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(138, 206, 174)
shp.Line.Weight = 1
End If
Next
```

...and the clicked shape needs to be changed as such:

```
With Selection.ShapeRange
.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(208, 209, 208)
.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
.Line.Weight = 6
```

Comment: Is the clicked shape a *group* of shapes, or just one shape? Wondering based on the `ShapeRange` in the second snippet.

Comment: Look at `Application.Caller`, so `ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)` should give you the clicked-on shape.

Comment: @BigBen, the clicked shape is just one shape.

Comment: Then Tim's answer is exactly what you need.

Comment: I have to add to mannually : ThisWorkbook.Sheets("xxx").Shapes(x89).Select to continue and execute the second snipet

Comment: wow , fantastic, please, @TimWilliams, answer the question so I can properly award you and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at using `Application.Caller` - inside a method called from a click on a shape, this will give you the name of the clicked shape.

So something like:

```
Dim shp As Shape
Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
```

should give you the clicked-on shape.